# Can you create templates in VIM with placeholders?

Tags: vim

Can you create a template in VIM with placeholders, and then it would cycle through the placeholders so you can fill in the content.

If the placeholder was used elsewhere, that would automatically get filled in since you already provided a definition for that placeholder.

example:

```
public class $CLASSNAME$
{
   public $CLASSNAME$
   {

   }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are [plenty of snippets plugins](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category%3aAutomated_Text_Insertion) for vim. You could try snipmate or [snippetsemu](http://code.google.com/p/snippetsemu/) for example.

Answer (score 2):

The vim plugin [snipmate](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate) already does precisely what you want to do. (Take a look at the [screencast](http://vimeo.com/3535418))

**Edit:** Changed to active github repo of vim-snipmate (thanks [Peter Rincker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438329/peter-rincker))

Comment: You may want to mention that msanders no longer updates snipmate. This fork is however: https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate

Comment: I've tried the new SnipMate two weeks ago. It had a lot of dependencies and didn't work at all. YMMV but it's probably safer to choose the old one.